# approximating large numbers

Tags: equation-solving, approximation

I want to get the zeros of a function $f(w,a)$ with respect to $a$. Thats not the problem. But the problem is, that the zeros are very large numbers. And I want them to be displayed in a short approximate notation. So for example 18282312390123 would become 10^13. My code looks sth like this.

```
IN: Solve[f(w,a)==0,a]
OUT: {a->Root[large number*w +large number*w^2+.....}
```

and I want it to like this

```
IN:Solve[f(w,a==0,a]
OUT:{a->Root[10^14*w+10^45*w^2+....}
```

IS there a function or sth that can help me with that ?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! It will be much easier to help if you provide your actual code. You can also try with [`ScientificForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ScientificForm.html). In [my example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBW9t.png), the number is automatically shown in the scientific notation.

Comment: @Domen: the code is probably more than a hundred thousand digits long because of the large numbers. I dont think post are allowed to be that long

Comment: @Domen I've tried it. It doesnt work. I think because it doesnt approximate. My large numbers are exact to the last digget. That why this large number needs to be approximated in order to be able to use scientific form

Comment: You could try_ `StringForm["10^``", Round[RealExponent[18282312390123]]]`

Comment: @Daniel Huber: Thank you. That works